# Rendering of controls in a moving panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I wonder why this example below acts like it does. When I click the button the panel is moving properly, but the buttons in it appears after the panel have finished its movement.

Why is it acting this way? Is it a flaw of panel, or the code?

Edit: Also, the panel seems to recolor things lying behind. Is there a way to recolor components so it doesn't?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testMeny
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Panel menu;
    int menuSpeed = 1;
    Boolean menuHidden = true;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

        menu = new Panel();
        menu.Size = new Size(100, 500);
        menu.Location = new Point(-100, 0);
        menu.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
        Controls.Add(menu);

        Point loc = new Point(10, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = String.Format("Knapp {0}", i + 1);
            b.Location = loc;
            loc.Offset(0, 50);
            b.Size = new Size(80, 40);
            menu.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = menuSpeed.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(menuHidden) {
            menu.BringToFront();
            for (int i = 0; i < menu.Size.Width; i++)
            {
                menu.Location = new Point(menu.Location.X+1, 0);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < menu.Size.Width; i++)
            {
                menu.Location = new Point(menu.Location.X - 1, 0);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            }
        }
        menuHidden = !menuHidden;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Painting can only occur when your UI thread goes idle and stops executing code.  It is not idle, you turned it into a zombie.  It is dead to the world, not doing anything useful since it is sleeping.  It cannot paint anything when it is asleep.  Use a Timer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Refresh() to repaint the form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (menuHidden)
    {
        menu.BringToFront();
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.Size.Width; i++)
        {
            menu.Location = new Point(menu.Location.X + 1, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            Refresh(); // <-----------------------
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.Size.Width; i++)
        {
            menu.Location = new Point(menu.Location.X - 1, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
            Refresh(); // <-----------------------
        }
    }
    menuHidden = !menuHidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first pass I would probably have put the animation effect in the `Form_Load` method to ensure the form is fully displayed before starting to manipulate it. If the screen is not updating well, try calling `Invalidate` against the form between every update (will cause the form to redraw).  If you want to get advanced, calculate the bounding rectangle of the old position and the new position and only invalidate that (for better speed).

You may find there are other issues with updates while the animation runs as you're not giving time for the message queue to process. The best way to handle this is to set up a timer and only update the animation once every tick, cancelling the timer once you have finished the animation. You can experiment with the timer interval to make it the right speed.